# Template argument without typename

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I was reading the [the following question and its associated accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549237/template-parameter-function-pointer-with-variadic-arguments) on SO and I was wondering what was the meaning of the second template parameter of the `struct C` (the one without the `typename` keyword).

Here is the code:

```
template<typename T, T> struct C; // Here.

template<typename T, typename R, typename ...Args, R (T::*F)(Args...)>
struct C<R (T::*)(Args...), F> 
{
    R operator()(T &obj, Args&&... args) 
    {
        return (obj.*F)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

I know what the code is doing but I do not figured out the purpose of the second `T` of the `template<typename T, T> struct C;` declaration and its meaning without the `typename` keyword.

Could someone tell me its meaning? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: And c++17 would allow `template<auto> struct C;` and `template<typename T, typename R, typename ...Args, R (T::*F)(Args...)>
struct C<F> {/*...*/};` specialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's template value parameter.

```
template<typename T, T> struct C;
```

Means that you define the type T, then also pass a value of type T into the template. In the example in the SO question, the type was a function pointer type, then the value for the second T was an actual pointer to a function of matching type.

Answer (score 0):

`T` is already defined in the first `typename T`,

So if you add `class` or again `typename T` in the second T, you will get:

```
error C2991: redefinition of template parameter 'T'
```

Comment: Yes, but why do we have to declare two template parameters with the same type?

Comment: I missed your question, but I think that you already have an answer on behalf of  `Jason Lang`